# Beta distribution "support" over interval $[0, 1]$ .... why will it not integrate to $1$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

I am trying to understand the Beta probability distribution. According to the textbook, the distribution has "support" over the interval $[0, 1]$. My understanding is that this is a Probability Density Function (PDF). If that is the case, then why when we compute the integral of this **from 0 to 1** is the result not equal to 1?
$$ \operatorname{Beta}(x\mid a,b) = \frac1{B(a,b)}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}$$
I have tried integrating it in a number of different ways. First, I worked out the integral. Then I used a calculus approximation technique (the Trapezoid Rule with the number of trapezoids equal to $200$). With both of these attempts, I got the same answer (which is no where near $1$): $0.009995$

Thanks in advance

Comment: $B(a,b)$ is *by definition* the integral of the numerator from $0$ to $1$. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: You don't even have to evaluate the integral. Just look at the very definition of the bera function and you will understand why that function you have above integrates to $1$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: Did you do this with particular numbers in the roles of $a$ and $b\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  yes, I did try it with particular numbers. First attempt was with **a** and **b** both 0.5 (less than one to create the "bimodal" effect) and the next few attempts was with them both greater than or equal to one. I'm starting to think they all should have come out to 1, but they did not.

Comment: @b00nheT  thank you for the fast reply. But the Wikipedia article you gave me is the one I was having trouble understanding. So you're saying that the integral **from 0 to 1 inclusive** will work out to be exactly 1 (for all acceptable values of a and b)?

Comment: Maybe that's your answer: perhaps the vertical asymptotes at $0$ and $1$ when $a$ and $b$ are less than $1$ require more attention to detail than do the places where the density is more well behaved.

Comment: Can you redo the numerical calculation with a=b=1, and report the value of B(a,b) that you are using as well as the trapezoid rule answer?

Comment: @kimchilover  I re-did the calculation and at a=b=1, the 1/B(a,b) turns out to be exactly 1

Comment: @josh there is no difference between an integral of a function from zero to one inclusive and an integral from zero to one exclusive. There's also no difference between a continuous RV having support $(0,1)$ and having support $[0,1]$

Comment: @josh In the $a=b=1$ case, what did the trapezoid rule answer come out to be?

Comment: @kimchilover it turns out to be the same. With n=200 where n is the number of trapezoids, we get 0.009995 (this is rounded off to 6 decimal places)

Comment: Is it possible you have a mistake in your trapezoid rule code?

Comment: @kimchilover  I got the EXACT same answer with both the approximation (trapezoid rule) and the actual working out of the integral. Which was quite a coincidence. Its weird. But I could have made a mistake in both. I worked both out several times though, so I'm not sure

Comment: What do you get with n=300 intervals?

Comment: @Josh What?? For $a=b=1,$ you worked out by hand $\int_0^1 x^{0}(1-x)^0 dx = .009995 $? How? Last I checked that integral is $1$ and doesn't need much working out. The correct value for $a=b=1/2$ is not obvious but it turns out to be $\pi.$ It will be hard to get numerically close though unless you use a very fine mesh near the endpoints since most of the area is right near the endpoints. When I integrate it with 200 points I still get like $10\%$ error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By very definition
$$\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\, dx=:B(a,b).$$
Consequently by diving both sides by $B(a,b)$ one obtains
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(a,b)}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\, dx=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you did this with $a=b=1/2,$ I suspect the vertical asymptotes at $0$ and $1$ (which occur when $a$ and $b$ are less than $1$) require more attention to detail than do the places where the density is more well behaved.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you mean. But the textbook quite clearly said [0, 1] and not (0, 1). Which is weird because the edges do in fact asymptote. How would you suggest going about integrating the edges? Taking limits?

Comment: Including or excluding an isolated point ($0$ or $1$) won't affect the value of the integral.